# Issues while installing the Extensibility Accelerator add-on for UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, web-extensibility

I have UFT version 12.2 on my machine and I am trying to install the **"Extensibility Accelerator" add-on** to UFT, but I am facing some issues there.

It gives me the following error :

> Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Shell SP1 Run-Time Components are missing on this machine, Please install all missing prerequisits and run this installation again.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the pre-requisites and should be installed automatically when you install the setup. Are you by any chance running the `.msi` directly?

In any case you can install this [directly from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19670) and then try re-running the installation of *Extensibility Accelerator*.